# Do two different pragma for-s have a barrier between them

Tags: c, openmp, barrier

There are 8 cities. we do calculations for different stats of each city.

I need to know if there is a barrier at the end of a for loop, so that the next group of calculation starts after all other previous cities' stats are done.

It must be like this, because each calculation depends from the previous one.

```
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    // calculate stats about population
}

// is there a barrier in here?
// Or do I need an explicit barrier
// #pragma omp barrier

#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    // calculate stats about cars 
}

// is there a barrier in here?

#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    // calculate stats about weather 
}

// ...same idea
```

Comment: Assuming you meant `#pragma omp parallel for`, yes, there is an implicit barrier at the end of the loop to wait for all threads to finish. Only a single thread will continue the execution flow until the next `#pragma ...`.

Comment: So I don't need an explicit barrier after each for loop? Ok. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use `#pragma omp parallel for`, you will have an **implicit barrier** at the end of the loop waiting for all threads to finish before continuing the execution.

You **don't need** to place an explicit `pragma omp barrier`.

According to [OpenMP 4.0 Complete Specifications](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) (1.3 line 10):

> The task region of the task being executed by the encountering thread
>   is suspended, and each member of the new team executes its implicit
>   task. **There is an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel
>   construct.**

Answer (score 2):

Aziz answer is correct but incomplete.

```
#pragma omp for
```

Without the `parallel` is still perfectly fine.

Any worksharing construct in OpenMP (including the loop construct `omp for`), has an implicit barrier at the end. This can be disabled with the `nowait` clause.

It is not necessary to use `omp parallel for`, that would also be inadvisable due to increased thread management overhead.

Comment: I though that it was understood that the above code is inside a `#pragma omp parallel` clause. But, thanks for the `nowait` clause.

Comment: Yes, I do understand your code is *within* a parallel construct. Note that Aziz answer explicitly only refers to **`#pragma omp parallel for`** - which is not what you use. But you're fine as well with just `omp for`...